# Putting string inside if/else brackets?

Tags: c, string, if-statement, char

I am a beginner in TurboC, my problem is putting a 'word' (string) inside the if/else statement, and then its output is on printf

here is my wrong code

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    int enter;
    string thisword;

    clrscr();
    printf("Press number 1 then enter ");

    scanf("%i",&enter);

    if(enter==1){
        thisword = 'Thanks';
    }
    else{
        thisword = 'Error';
    }


    printf("\n%s",thisword);

    getch();
    return.0;
}
```

i dont want to put printf as a statements in every if/else brackets like

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    int enter;

    clrscr();
    printf("Press number 1 then enter ");

    scanf("%i",&enter);

    if(enter==1){
        printf("\n Thanks");
    }
    else{
        printf("\n Error");
    }    
    getch();
    return.0;
}
```

Comment: does your program compile properly? You are using `string` which is in C++

Comment: [Useful link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style).....

Comment: C does not and never has had a native string type. By convention, the language uses arrays of char terminated with a null char, i.e., with '\0'.

Comment: Not that it's here, but I frequently see this in C code when someone is using that near-worthless `cs50.h` header from Harvard that does `typedef char *string;` (man, I wanna meet the ignoramus that thought *that* was a great thing to teach beginners). They should stick to spitting out courtroom jesters and leave the engineering to other schools.

Comment: Define macro (#define string char*) or typedef (char * string) and use double quotation for string assignment.

Comment: Hint: don't use TurboC, this product is 20 (or is is it 30 ?) years old.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: 24 if we use the last release (Wikipedia). Worse:it does not support standard C, not even modern C which started with C99. I can't understand why this zombie is still used in courses.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It is 28 years old and has been dead for around 20 years.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Turbo C, but the "string" type does not exist in C.

- Use char * type
- Use double quote " not simple quote ' for string

Your code will work as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int enter;
    char *thisword;

    printf("Press number 1 then enter ");
    scanf("%i",&enter);

    if (enter == 1) {
        thisword = "Thanks";
    }
    else {
        thisword = "Error";
    }
    printf("\n%s",thisword);
    return.0;
}
```

Comment: `I don't know Turbo C`..congratulations, you have a good chance in actually learning C. :)

Comment: _Use parenthesis with your `return`_: this is not a requirement at all. It's a matter of style, but putting people put rarely parentheses with `return`. It's useless and it makes the `return` statement look like a function call.

Comment: Yes. Please remove the subjective nonsense about the return statement from an otherwise good answer. There's no need to teach obscure and highly subjective coding styles to beginners.

Comment: Copy that, you're right

Answer (score -2):

You should write

```
thisword = "Thanks";
```

and not

```
thisword = 'Thanks';
```

Comment: This pretends `string thisword;` is fine, which it of course is not so it still won't build with this change alone.